# Where would I look at if I want to know all comment activities of my Facebook friends?

Tags: facebook, comments

I see that my friends comment/like something here in the #1 box as below:

[image: Feeds and Chat]

but I cannot see it my list (some friends are added into list). Some of their comments (on other photos) are even not shown anywhere until I read it directly.

Where would I look to see all comment activities of my friends?

Comment: My current answer may be to add those friends who you want to see that in the `close friends` list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Facebook Graph Search for this

"Posts commented on by my friends"

https://www.facebook.com/search/me/friends/stories-commented/

"Posts liked by my friends"

https://www.facebook.com/search/me/friends/stories-liked/